# How to dynamically replace content in TinyMCE using Meteor Blaze

Tags: javascript, meteor, tinymce, meteor-blaze

I am using tinyMCE in meteor and within the tinyMCE text area I want to set the student name.

I want to replace {{student}} after the user picks a student from the list with the students name.

Currently I have:

```
    var editor = tinyMCE.get('mytextarea'); 
    var content = editor.getContent();
    content = content.replace(/{{\$student}}/g, text); 
    editor.setContent(content);
```

This however does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could make a TinyMCE fiddle so people can see your code in the context of the HTML page.

Comment: Fiddle link to my code - [link](https://jsfiddle.net/xx6tt37n/)

Comment: That fiddle does not run for me ... errors regarding Template being not defined.